# Is it possible to detect the PHP file request

Tags: php

For example we have this URL:
https://www.domain.com/pdf.php?url=http://www.domain.com/report.php?id=341

I would like to know if it's possible to somehow detect using PHP in `report.php` that `pdf.php` is trying to open access `report.php?id=341`.

If that's possible I would limit later on that report.php can be called only by pdf.php, invoice.php etc.

BASICALY I want to make sure that report.php is requested by server and not human.

Is there perhaps a security risk?

I hope my question make sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are pdf.php and report.pdf on the same domain?

Comment: Learn about `$_SERVER['']` variables, and you will know how to achieve this

Comment: Just a side not, you probably want to escape the second query string connected to the first query string as you will probably confuse some browsers.

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie I've checked, but with using $_SERVER[''] variables, I can't effectively achiev this.

Comment: If you are trying to restrict access to report.php, it would probably be better to just have pdf.php pass a key through the url that is generated in pdf.php (or whatever other script) and report.php can validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following to display the full contents of the $_SERVER array. It will show you the required variable you are looking for.

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see where the user came from using

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

For example

```
if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "valid_url.php" ) ...
```

This is not secure however, as the php manual states: This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: Tryed, but somehow I get blank $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to add you logic to `pdf.php`, `invoice.php` and etc.
There you should handle GET/POST parameters.
If you're using plain PHP make some function and place it at the start of all other web accessible php files. E.g.

```
if(!check_get_from($_GET)) die;
```

But the best practice is to have only one entry point (index.php).

Comment: I know, but I'm no able to. I will try to provide more details as my case is complex :P

Comment: Not able? They are on the same domain as you mentioned :)

Comment: Yes, but pdf.php is file that generate pdf for example, it's used for various tasks not just this one :S

Comment: If you're using plain PHP make some function and place it at the start of all other web accessible php files. E.g. if(!check_get_from($_GET)) die; But the best practice is to have only one entry point (index.php).